# How to create MVIEW containing dblink in postgresql

Tags: oracle, postgresql, view, dblink, materialized

I extracted MVIEW statements from oracle database and executing those statements in postgresql db.

I get below error:

ERROR:  syntax error at or near "@".
Syntax of MVIEW statement is : CREATE Materialized view XYS as select ***** from target@dblink.

I am not sure if postgresql mview recognizes or parsed '@' symbol or not. Please help.

Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SQL is standardized, but every database speaks its own dialect, so you cannot expect non-standard SQL statements to port from Oracle to PostgreSQL.

Rather than using a database link, you would use a foreign table in PostgreSQL, so depending on where the target table is, you would install postgres_fdw or oracle_fdw.

Besides, the `CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW` statements differ in PostgreSQL and Oracle. PostgreSQL only has what is called `REFRESH COMPLETE ON DEMAND` in Oracle, so odds are you will have to redesign a little.